# What does NoLanguage language mode in PowerShell really mean?

Tags: powershell, jea

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm looking to understand what the NoLanguage language mode means, I checked the Microsoft Documentation below but it is quite vague:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes?source=recommendations&view=powershell-7.3

Can someone give some examples what cmdlets I wouldn't be able to run in the NoLanguage language mode?